# Sonar startup error

Tags: sonarqube

I had earlier downloaded sonar version 2.13.1. I unzipped the same and did necessary configuration. On starting sonar, it would start up fine.

Today suddenly I am starting to get an exception while startup saying

java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: A device attached to the system is not functioning

I am using windows xp (x86-32). The JRE version is 1.7.

I am not sure if this is enough information to find the problem, hence attaching few lines of stack trace.

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: A device attached to the system is not functioning
     at com.kenai.jffi.Foreign$InValidInstanceHolder.getForeign(Foreign.java:90)
     at com.kenai.jffi.Foreign.getInstance(Foreign.java:95)
     at com.kenai.jffi.Library.openLibrary(Library.java:151)
     at com.kenai.jffi.Library.getCachedInstance(Library.java:125)
```

Answer (score 0):

Found this on [technet](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc978749.aspx):

> A device attached to the system is not functioning.
>
> Explanation:
>
> An attached device is not working for one of these reasons: (1) it is switched off, or connected improperly; (2) the floppy disk and drive types are incompatible; (3) the floppy disk is not properly inserted in the drive; (4) the drive door is open; or (5) the floppy disk is not properly formatted.
>
> User Action:
>
> Correct the problem and retry the command.

Is Sonar (or it's database) running on a removable filesystem?

Comment: Thanks Mark. No, neither sonar or its db running on removable filesystem.

Comment: Well, you should probably try to isolate the problem. You can start with a fresh install, and try to go step by step towards the current installation to see where the issue is.